# Undefined property: stdClass::$descripcion (View: C:\Proyectos Laravel\proyecto_ferreteria\resources\views\menu\adminProducto.blade.php)

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente error cuando quiero ingresar al apartado de productos en mi página web :

> Undefined property: stdClass::$descripcion (View: C:\Proyectos Laravel\proyecto_ferreteria\resources\views\menu\adminProducto.blade.php)

Este es mi código del `controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ProductoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $productos = DB::table('productos')->get();
        $categorias = DB::table('categorias')->get();
        return view('menu.adminProducto', ['productos' => $productos, 'categorias' => $categorias]);
    }

    public function viewProducto()
    {
        $productos = DB::table('productos')->get();        
        $categorias = DB::table('categorias')->get();
        return view('menu.productos', ['productos' => $productos, 'categorias' => $categorias]);
    }
    

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $producto = array (
            'nombre_producto'=> $request ->nombre_producto,
            'descripcion'=> $request ->descripcion,
            'id_categoria'=> $request ->id_categoria,
            'precio'=> $request ->precio,
            'status' => 1,
        );
        DB::table('productos')->insertGetId($producto);
        

        $productos = DB::table('productos')->get();
        $categorias = DB::table('categorias')->get();
        return view('menu.adminProducto', ['productos' => $productos, 'categorias' => $categorias]);

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

es un error comun, tienes algo, en tu caso la variable $descripcion pero el modelo no lo pasa a la vista y por consiguiente la vista no lo va a mostrar, en otras palabras dejaste la descripcion de un producto vacia y no controlas que pasa si llega vacia o inexistente a la vista.